# UPDATE com condições diferentes na mesma query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Como fazer um update em vários registros setando valores diferentes, exemplo:

```
$update = "UPDATE tabela SET ativo=1, nivel=2 WHERE nome ='jose'
                                              AND nome='maria'
                                              AND nome='joao'";
```

nesse caso quero apenas que o jose receba o **nivel=2** e o restante receber **nivel=1** na mesma query. e **ativo=1 pra todos**.

Estou usando PHP com PDO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode usar um `IF()`

```
UPDATE
   tabela
SET
   ativo = 1,
   nivel = IF( nome='jose', 2, 1 )
WHERE
   nome IN ( 'jose', 'maria', 'joao' );
```

Acho interessante como conhecimento, mas na prática não crie este tipo de atualização com muitas condições a não ser em casos onde realmente a vantagem seja evidente.

Comment: Obrigado, não sabia que dava pra usar IF dentro da query. Mas não vejo outra opção para meu sistema, no caso é um cadastro de grupo de alunos onde somente o líder do grupo recebe nivel 2 no momento do cadastro

Comment: Esse IF é uma função, equivale ao ternário de outras linguagens `expressão ? valor se verdadeiro : valor se falso` - no caso, se o primeiro parâmetro for verdadeiro, retorna o segundo, senão, retorna o terceiro.